# How to horizzontally center this image at the center of this page?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, margin

I am finding some HTML\CSS difficulties with this web page: http://www.saranistri.com/saranistriWPnew/?page_id=613

As you can see in this page there is an immage named: **abusivismo1-641x321.jpg**

This immage is into this div containers structure:

The div having clasas **vc_span12 wpb_column column_container** contains this other div having class **wpb_wrapper** that contains itself **wpb_single_image wpb_content_element centerizedImg** that contains the div having class **wpb_wrapper** that finnally contains my **abusivismo1-641x321.jpg**

I want to center this immage in its container in such a way that is at the center of the page

I have try to set some CSS settings like:

```
width: 642px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

but not work

Can you help me?

Tnx so much

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
.wpb_content_element.wpb_single_image img {
    display: table;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Replace the above values in your class `.wpb_content_element.wpb_single_image img` and your image will be at the center.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this style to that class :

```
.wpb_single_image.wpb_content_element.centerizedImg {

text-align:center

}
```

if you want sure to get only the images centered, style your wrapper of the images with display:inline-block;

just a simple solution without margins.

Answer (score 0):

in order to centralize any element, you may use

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

also, an element will stay at center if it's patent has a `text-align: center`

You may also have a look at **[Dead Centre](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use `text-align:center;` for your `wpb_wrapper` class. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRzRm/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` it will horizontally align to center.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, depending for what you use this, the image is not resized automatically when you resize the browser; i.e. mobile browsers. I came up with this:

```
.wpb_wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px; /* adds some white space in left/right on mobile */
}
```

Hope it helps someone.